# Indexing in ServiceNow Jelly Report not working

Tags: javascript, html, indexing, servicenow, jelly

I have to create a custom report on a ServiceNow UI Page using Javascript and HTML/Jelly. Everything is working except for this line:

`<td>${jelly.jvar_bucket.timebuckets[idx].totalSystem;} </td>`

If I replace `idx` with a number, say 20 or 25, then the report shows as expected. With idx it is all blanks.

Here is the full script.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<j:jelly trim="false" xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:g="glide" xmlns:j2="null" xmlns:g2="null">
<g:ui_form> 
<g:evaluate var="jvar_surveys" object="true" jelly="true">
        var bucket = [];
<!-- // Helper function to determine AM or PM from hour -->
        function timeflip(hour) 
        {
            if(hour &gt; 12)
            {
                return "PM";
            }
            if(hour == 12)
            {
                return "PM";
            }
            if(hour &lt; 12)
            {
                return "AM";
            }
        } <!-- end function timeflip -->
        var buckets = [];
 
        var ind = 0;
        var hour = 0;
        while(ind &lt; 48)
        {
            var itm = {};
            var h = hour;
            var daynight = "AM";
        if(hour &gt; 12)
        {
            h = hour-12;
            daynight = "PM";
        }
        if(hour == 12)
        {
            h = hour;
            daynight = "PM";
        }
        var notWhole =  (h - Math.floor(h)) !== 0;
                    if(notWhole)
                        {
                            h = Math.floor(h);
                            if(h == 0 &amp;&amp; daynight=='PM')
                            {h=12};
                            itm.interval = (h) +":30 "+timeflip(hour)+" - "+(h+1)+":00 "+timeflip(hour+1) ;
                            if(h == 12 &amp;&amp; daynight=='PM')
                            itm.interval = (h) +":30 "+timeflip(hour)+" - "+(h-11)+":00 "+timeflip(hour) ;
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            h = Math.floor(h);
                            itm.interval = h +":00 "+timeflip(hour)+" - "+h+":30 "+timeflip(hour);
                        }
 
                    itm.totalInterviewer = itm.totalSystem = itm.totalRow = 0;
                    hour += 0.5;
                    ind++;
                    buckets.push(itm);
                }
<!-- TOP HALF SCRIPT -->
        var ga = new GlideRecord('x_igngr_fema_cati_study_table');
        ga.query();
        while(ga.next())
        {
            var obj = {};
            var stdy = ga.study_type.getDisplayValue();
            obj.timebuckets = buckets;  
            obj.study_type = stdy;
            obj.totComp = ga.surveys_completed.getDisplayValue();
            obj.totQuota = ga.quota_study.getDisplayValue();
            obj.intNames = ga.study_interviewer.getDisplayValue();
            if(obj.intNames.trim() === ""){
                obj.intCount = 0;
            } else {
                var splitNames = obj.intNames.split(',');
                obj.intCount = splitNames.length;
            }
            var totAtt = 0
            var attempts = new GlideRecord('x_igngr_fema_cati_piror_attempts');
            attempts.addEncodedQuery('survey_record.collection_cycle.status=open');
            attempts.query();
            while(attempts.next()) {
                totAtt += 1;
            }
            obj.totAtt = totAtt;
            <!-- Time buckets -->
                <!-- var timeBuckets = buckets; -->
                var interviewerGrandTotal = 0; 
                var systemGrandTotal = 0;
                
                var surveyRecord = new GlideRecord('x_igngr_fema_cati_survey_record');
                surveyRecord.addEncodedQuery('study_type.study_type='+stdy);
                surveyRecord.addQuery('in_queue=true^callback_date_timeISNOTEMPTY');
                surveyRecord.addQuery('schedule_status=by_interviewer^ORschedule_status=unmet^ORschedule_status=no_answer');
                <!-- surveyRecord.addQuery('schedule_status=no_answer'); -->
                surveyRecord.query();
                while(surveyRecord.next())
                {
                    var t = surveyRecord.callback_date_time;
                    var startTime = new GlideDateTime(t);
                    var testtime = startTime.getDisplayValueInternal();
                    var finalTime = new GlideDateTime(testtime);
                    var mSecs = finalTime.getTime().getNumericValue();
                    var min = mSecs / (1000 * 60); 
                    var b = Math.floor(min / 30);
                    if (b >= 18 &amp;&amp; 39 >= b){
                        if(surveyRecord.schedule_status == 'no_answer')
                        {
                            var tot = obj.timebuckets[b].totalSystem;
                            obj.timebuckets[b].totalSystem = tot + 1;
                            obj.timebuckets[b].totalRow = obj.timebuckets[b].totalRow + tot + 1;
                            systemGrandTotal = systemGrandTotal + 1;
                        }
                    else{
                        var tot = obj.timebuckets[b].totalInterviewer;
                        obj.timebuckets[b].totalInterviewer = tot + 1;
                        obj.timebuckets[b].totalRow = obj.timebuckets[b].totalRow + tot + 1;
                        interviewerGrandTotal = interviewerGrandTotal + 1;

                    }     
                    } 
                }
            bucket.push(obj);
        }
</g:evaluate>
</g:ui_form>
<center>
</center> 
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <h1>All Studies Scheduling Report</h1>
</div> 
<table id="exportTable" name="exportTable" class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th rowspan="2">Study</th> 
<j:forEach var="jvar_key" items="${bucket}">
    <th style="text-align: center" colspan="2">${jvar_key.study_type}</th>
</j:forEach>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<g:evaluate jelly="true">
            
</g:evaluate>   
<tr>
<th scope="row">Total Quota</th>
    <j:forEach var="jvar_key" items="${bucket}">
        <th style="text-align: center" colspan="2">${jvar_key.totQuota}</th>
    </j:forEach>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row">Total Completes</th>
    <j:forEach var="jvar_key" items="${bucket}">
        <th style="text-align: center" colspan="2">${jvar_key.totComp}</th>
    </j:forEach>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row">Total Attempts</th>
    <j:forEach var="jvar_key" items="${bucket}">
        <th style="text-align: center" colspan="2">${jvar_key.totAtt}</th>
    </j:forEach>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row">Number of Interviewers Assigned</th>
    <j:forEach var="jvar_key" items="${bucket}">
        <th style="text-align: center" colspan="2">${jvar_key.intCount}</th>
    </j:forEach>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row">Names of Assigned Interviewers</th>
    <j:forEach var="jvar_key" items="${bucket}">
        <th style="text-align: center" colspan="2">${jvar_key.intNames}</th>
    </j:forEach>
</tr>
<tr>  
<th>Queue Time Interval</th>
<j:forEach var="jvar_key" items="${bucket}">
    <th bgcolor="EBF3FC">System Scheduled Record Count</th>
    <th bgcolor="EBF3FC">Interviewer Scheduled Callback Record Count</th>
</j:forEach>

</tr>
<g:evaluate jelly="true">
    var idx = 0;
</g:evaluate>
<j:forEach items="${buckets}" var="jvar_field_name">

    <j:if test="${idx >= 18 &amp;&amp; 39 >= idx }">
    <tr>
    <td scope="row">${jvar_field_name.interval;}</td>
    
     <j:forEach items="${bucket}" var="jvar_bucket">
        
        <!-- <g:evaluate jelly="true">
            var interval = jvar_bucket.timebuckets[idx].interval;
            var interviewer = jvar_bucket.timebuckets[idx].totalInterviewer;
            var system = jvar_bucket.timebuckets[idx].totalSystem;
            if (interviewer == 0)
            {
                interviewer = "";
            }
            if (system == 0)
            {
                system = "";
            }
        </g:evaluate>    -->
        
        <td>${jvar_bucket.timebuckets[idx].totalSystem;} </td>
        <td>${jvar_bucket.timebuckets[idx].totalInterviewer;} </td>
        
    <!-- <j:forEach begin="0" end="2" items="${bucket}" var="jvar_bucket">
        <td>${jvar_bucket.timebuckets.totalSystem;}</td>
        <td>${idx} </td>
    </j:forEach> -->
    </j:forEach>
    </tr>   
    </j:if> 
    <g:evaluate jelly="true">
        idx++;
    </g:evaluate>
</j:forEach>
<tr class="success">
<th>Total</th>
<!-- <td>${systemGrandTotal}</td>
<td>${interviewerGrandTotal}</td> -->
</tr>
</tbody>
 
</table>
 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-2 col-md-2" style="position: relative; bottom: 0; right: 0;" onClick="tableToCSV()">Export Report </button>

</j:jelly>
```

Comment: What do you get if you temporarily add this? `<td data-idx="${idx}">${jvar_bucket.timebuckets[idx].totalSystem;}</td>` That is to say, what is the rendered content of `data-idx`? Is it what you expect it to be ( i.e 18 <= int <= 39)?

Comment: the report shows blank when I add this line and comment out: <td>${jvar_bucket.timebuckets[idx].totalSystem;} </td><td>${jvar_bucket.timebuckets[idx].totalInterviewer;} </td>

Comment: OK, and if you leave some dummy data inside it, and add the `idx` as I suggested? For example: `<td data-idx="${idx}">foo bar</td>` . When you look at the generated / rendered code, what is the value for `data-idx`?

Comment: like this?

"<td scope="row">${jvar_field_name.interval;}</td>
  <j:forEach items="${bucket}" var="jvar_bucket">
  <td data-idx="${idx}">foo bar</td>
  <td data-idx="${idx}">${jvar_bucket.timebuckets[idx].totalSystem;}</td>
  <td>${jvar_bucket.timebuckets[38].totalSystem;} </td>
  <td>${jvar_bucket.timebuckets[20].totalInterviewer;} </td>"